# Can anyone tell why this C function isn't working?

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault

So, I'm doing an exercise, and I want to sort a list of float numbers. **When I used for loop, it worked perfectly**. When I changed to while loop, it shows nothing. **I already tried to declare a different variable for each while loop, but remains the same.** I'm getting this warning for the file ex005.c:

```
Please, input one non-integer values: 45.3
Please, input one non-integer values: 32.2
Please, input one non-integer values: 34.5
zsh: segmentation fault  ./"ex005"
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float   three_numbers[3];
    char    support_var;
    int     size_array;
    int     i;
    int     z;

        size_array = 3;
        z = size_array - 1;
        i = 0;
    while (i < size_array)
    {
        printf("Please, input one non-integer values: ");
        scanf("%f", &three_numbers[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < size_array)
    {
        while (z != i)
        {
            if (three_numbers[i] < three_numbers[z])
            {
                support_var = three_numbers[i];
                three_numbers[i] = three_numbers[z];
                three_numbers[z] = support_var;
            }
            z--;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < size_array)
    {
        printf("The %dth place is %.1f. \n", i + 1, three_numbers[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Since it is likely you have clang or gcc, I suggest you compile it yourself with `-fsanitize=address,undefined -g` and then run again!

Comment: You should set `z` just before the loop that uses it, like you did with `i`. Not somewhere else. It will go under-range.

Comment: `proc.c:25:49: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'float [3]'` i.e. your `z` becomes -1.

Comment: @WeatherVane, ma man, you nailed it. Its exactly that. THANK YOU. I've been  struggling with this for hours!

Comment: With a debugger you might have nailed it in seconds. I nailed it by inspection without running it.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I'll keep that in mind. I'm new using C and I don't know how to use a debugger. I'll learn that. Thank you again.

Comment: @moxú so did you try `gcc -fsanitize=address,undefined -g yourfile.c` - it will catch stuff that is wrong in your program *even if* it looks *as if it works right*.

Comment: A debugger will be the single most valuable tool in your box, and repay every moment spent learning how to use it.

Comment: Also, with debug prints you would have solved it quickly. I mean like `printf("line %u: i=%d z=%d\n", __LINE__, i, z);`, and copy-paste that liberally to places where i and z are changed.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні, I tried to get back to the code that wasn't running but it starts running right... So this didn't did anything. I'll tried to test incase anything goes wrong in another task! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set `z` in the inner loop otherwise it causes out of bound access of `three_numbers[z]`.  Also, your `support_var` should be a float.  Use the `typeof` operator if available (with gcc 10.2.1-6 it's still an extension so `-std=gnu18`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 3

int main(void) {
    float three_numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Please, input one non-integer values: ");
        scanf("%f", three_numbers + i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int z = ARRAY_SIZE - 1; z != i; z--) {
            if(three_numbers[i] < three_numbers[z]) {
                // typeof (*three_numbers) support_var = three_numbers[i];
                float support_var = three_numbers[i];
                three_numbers[i] = three_numbers[z];
                three_numbers[z] = support_var;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("The %dth place is %.1f. \n", i + 1, three_numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Not sure why you don't like for-loops but it makes your code easier to read.  Also replaced `int array_size` with a constant ARRAY_SIZE. Minimizing scope of variables makes is usually a good idea.